# pin manipulation assembly - write/read to/from specific pins

Tags: assembly

How do I write ones to only the lower nibble (pin0-3) at the same time in assembly (and not use "out PORTx, 0x0f" because it writes zeros to the high nibble)? And how to read from the same pins, without getting all pins info?

All the best,
AVR-08

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide what you have done (codesample).

Comment: Use OR with the old value of the port to set some bits without modifying others.

Comment: Great! Thank you, Peter and Jaques!!

Comment: What assembler/CPU are you using? Based upon your one example instruction, I'd assume perhaps x86, but it's not clear. On x86, you can't just read select bits from a port. You have to read the whole port, at least 8 bits. You can then mask out any bits you wish from that value. The standard method for setting specific bits is to read the current port (whole value), only set/clear the bits you wish to, then write the whole port value back. If the port value is not readable, you could keep a persistent, local copy in memory that represents the last value written and use that.

Comment: Yes, x86 - your right!
So, I'll read the whole port, mask out the bits I like to change, change them and then write back.
Many Thanks, lurker!!
(I'm creating the interface/code for using a keyboard)